Decaying functions on positive reals are Laplace transforms of signed measures
Given any function $f(t)$ that decays on $[0, \infty)$ to zero (but is not necessarily monotonic), is it possible to show that it can be represented as the Laplace transform of a signed Borel measure $\mu$ as
\begin{align*}
f(t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}d\mu(s).
\end{align*}
We know by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem that any such function $f(t)$ can be uniformly approximated by a sum of signed decaying exponentials but this is not enough to prove that it has a representation as such.
From the classical book of Feller ("An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications"), by Theorem 2a XIII.1 pg. 433, we know that if a sum of positive exponentials
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_ie^{-\alpha_i t}
\end{align*}
converged pointwise to $f(t)$, then defining the measures
\begin{align*}
\mu_n(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i\delta(\alpha - \alpha_i)
\end{align*}
this would imply that there exists a limiting positive measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to it and $f(t)$ is the Laplace transform of this measure. Another way to see that $f(t)$ is the Laplace transform of a positive measure $\mu$ is directly through Bernstein's theorem on completely monotonic functions.
However, an analogous statement for infinitely differentiable functions $f(t)$ that can be approximated by signed exponentials does not exist. It seems like such a statement should be true, but I have not managed to prove it. Would this result require simply redoing the convergence analysis of Feller for signed Borel measures rather than positive Borel measures? Any suggestions or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe it's possible to consider Hahn decomposition of measure and apply results for signed measures?

The problem is I am trying to prove existance of the limiting measure $\mu$.

The set of complex $t$ for which the integral converges is a half-plane $\text{Re}(t) > \alpha$, possibly including some points of the boundary $\text{Re}(t) = \alpha$.  In the open half-plane, $f(t)$ is analytic.
So if your function can't be extended to an analytic function on the right half-plane, it's not a Laplace transform.

I believe that for any sufficiently decaying function $f(t)$ I can define its analytic signal $f_a = f + iH[f]$ where $H$ denotes the Hilbert transform. This has only positive frequencies, and therefore by the Paley-Wiener theorem, it can be extended analytically to the positive half-plane. So I can't really use this argument to show that some decaying functions are not representable as a Laplace transform, but I might have made a mistake in this argument.

If, for instance, $f$ is not differentiable, there's no way for this to work.
Or try $f(t) = 1/(2 - 2 t +t^2)$ which is meromorphic but has poles at $1 \pm i$. (For $\text{Re}(t) > 1$ this is the Laplace transform of $e^s \sin(s)$, but you wanted $t \in [0,\infty)$).  Even if you're willing to accept a case where the integral is only valid for sufficiently large $t$, try something like $f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/((n^2 - 2 n t + t^2 + 1) n)$ which has poles at $n \pm i$ for all positive integers $n$.

Okay perfect, that is so helpful! I in fact know in the special case I am interested in that f is infinitely differentiable. So that rules out these counterexamples and perhaps there is a way forward to prove the result.
